# How to stop service account credential printing on Jenkins console?

Tags: jenkins, google-container-registry

I have Jenkins server which builds project, build docker image and push it to Google Container Registry.

I am using service account to login to GCR using command `docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat ${service-account.json})" https://gcr.io` as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file)

When this line is executed, content of service-account.json file is printed on console in Jenkins pipeline.

How would I stop credential being printed on console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use the --password-stdin flag.

`cat ${service-account.json} | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io`

> Provide a password using STDIN. To run the docker login command non-interactively, you can set the --password-stdin flag to provide a password through STDIN. **Using STDIN prevents the password from ending up in the shell’s history, or log-files.**

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

Note: The password file should only include the password,  and should not be json encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the JSON Key File and the username associated with it as a credential in Jenkins, you can then reference the key file inside of a withCredentials step (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

Any credentials used inside of a withCredentials step will be masked automatically

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I tried using following. I stored credential in file.

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'cred', variable: 'KEY')]) {
 container('docker') {
  sh "docker login -u _json_key -p ${KEY} https://gcr.io"
 }
}
```

I am getting error:

Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/: unknown: Unable to parse json key.